# How to get margin between columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How did he manage to get that margin between the cols?

http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/articles-layout

It's probably me being stupid not seeing it, but I can't figure out how he did it reading the code.

Edit:

Just figured out how he did it.

I first had this code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 thumb">
   ...
</div>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="thumb">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

And this seems to put a margin in between the cols. However, i'm still curious, how did this happen? And is there a way to make the margins smaller (or bigger)?

Comment: It's column padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 15px of padding on the right and left for the bootstrap class.

See image here: [Bootstrap padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR6E2.png).

On a side note to help you in the future, you can inspect the elements by pressing Ctrl-Shift-I on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the padding is part of Bootstrap's column classes. Do you have some example code that isn't applying the padding I can look at?

See the class I pasted below. The padding-left:15px and padding-right:15px; are what does it.

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Hey I edited my question with some code how I managed to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it my many ways i will show some example.

**Using Bootstrap alone.**

You can use

```
col-md-offset-1
```

Class with the div, it will gave some offset space between divs.
example : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

**Using Custom CSS**

Call a custom class for the div 
Give css properties

```
margin:0 x%
```